# Merge 2 tables into a new table, when the tables have same set of columns but unordered

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database with 2 tables suppose table1 & table2 each having the same set of 300 columns.
Now what I want to do is create a new table (eg. table3) consisting of rows from table1 and table2.
There is no row matching needed between the two tables. I tried `insert`, `union` and various other operations but the catch is the **columns are unordered inside the tables.** But they have the same set of column names.
[image: Refer to this image]
I want to merge the two tables with the rows having data in respective columns, which I am not able to do using UNION or INSERT operation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying a lot of different ways to merge the tables using SQL commands I was unable to find any solution which fulfilled the requirements.
One way in which this can be solved using Python is to load the tables into a Pandas dataframe and then concat these two to a new dataframe.
Pandas merge them properly by matching the column names and then you can reload the table to the database.

Any other solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can always explicitly specify column names instead of `insert into t values` and `select *`:

```
insert into t3(col1, col2, col3, ...)
select col1, col2, col3, ... from t1
union all
select col1, col2, col3, ... from t2
```

Comment: Thank you for giving this solution. This is surely one way to solve the problem, but I don't think this can be the feasible solution when there are a large number of columns like in my case where I have 300 columns. And I am looking for a more generalized solution that can be implemented for different tables without worrying about knowing the column names and the order in which they appear.

Comment: 300 column in table is an indication of poor design.

Comment: It is not a poor design if the situation requires them to be in that structure.
The normalization of tables depends on the use case, which here is not required.

Comment: @NavkarShah you could do `create table t3 like t1;` and then `insert into t3 select * from t1 union all select * from t2` assuming t1 and t2 have the same structure and you want all columns from both tables.